# Remove toggle class when other item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

On my mobile site I've got a vertical dropdown menu (like an accordion) where each parent item features a down-pointing arrow to indicate the drop-down. When the user clicks on the parent item the arrow rotates and when you click it again to close the drop-down it rotates back to it's original state. However, if you don't click the drop-down to close it but just click on another parent item the drop-down closes, but the arrow stays in the rotated position.
Here is the code :

```
$('li.nav-about').click(function () {
        $('#arrow-about').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });

$(' li.nav-industry').click(function () {
        $('#arrow-indusrty').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });

$('li.nav-application').click(function () {
        $('#arrow-application').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
```

Any suggestions how to remove the 'rotate' class when another item is clicked?

EDIT 
Here's what the mark up looks like :

```
<ul id="nav-list">

   <li class="nav-list_item nav-about"><a href="#">About Us</a><div class="arrow-down" id="arrow-about"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</li>


<li class="nav-list_item nav-products"><a href="#">Products</a><div class="arrow-down" id="arrow-products"></div>

  <ul>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: there is better solution we can suggest if you share the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the existent `rotate` class from every button before toggle the current like:

```
$('li.nav-about').click(function () {
        $('.rotate:not("#arrow-about")').removeClass("rotate");
        $('#arrow-about').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
 });

(' li.nav-industry').click(function () {
        $('.rotate:not("#arrow-indusrty")').removeClass("rotate");
        $('#arrow-indusrty').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });

$('li.nav-application').click(function () {
        $('.rotate:not("#arrow-application")').removeClass("rotate");
        $('#arrow-application').toggleClass("rotate");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works, however then it doesn't rotate back when you click on the parent item. So for example if I've got 'about' open and click it again to close it the arrow doesn't rotate back. If I click 'industry' though it does

Comment: @MariaL implemented in order to avoid itself

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change too much of your code, just try this.

```
$('li.nav-about').click(function () {
    $('#arrow-about').toggleClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-indusrty').removeClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-application').removeClass("rotate");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$(' li.nav-industry').click(function () {
    $('#arrow-about').removeClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-indusrty').toggleClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-application').removeClass("rotate");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$('li.nav-application').click(function () {
    $('#arrow-about').removeClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-indusrty').removeClass("rotate");
    $('#arrow-application').toggleClass("rotate");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Now you are sure that each element, instead of the selected one, will turn to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this.

```
var toggleNavigation = function(){
    var r_navigation = $('li.nav-about,li.nav-industry,li.nav-application');

    $(r_navigation).each(function(i, oNav){
        $(oNav).on('click',function(){
            if(!$(oNav).hasClass('rotate')){
                $(r_navigation).removeClass('rotate');
                $(oNav).addClass('rotate');
            }else{
               $(oNav).removeClass('rotate');
            }
        });
    });
};
```